# Como saber o quantitativo de inscritos

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

Em c# irei desenvolver um aplicativo para controle de visualizações e inscritos do meu canal...

Tentei inserir este código:

```
static long Inscritos(string youtube_addr){
var wb=new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate(youtube_addr); // Sendo http://youtube.com/user/meu_canal/about

var countAll = wb.Document.getElementsByTagName('b')[0];
retun Convert.ToInt64(countAll);
```

Ai na hora que eu chamo `MessageBox.Show(Inscritos('http://youtube.com/user/malena010102/about').ToString());`

o resultado é um texto em branco!

Comment: Você está pegando o conteúdo de uma *tag* de negrito? A primeira da página é o contador? Você sabe que isto é bem pouco confiável? O YouTube não tem uma API oficial? Se quiser insistir nisto considere pegar primeiro a *tag* com a classe `about-stat` e dentro dela pegar o que está em `<b>`. Mas eu acho que este tipo de classe que está usando não permite isto diretamente. Aí teria que ficar caçando, pode haver ambiguidade. Ou seja, não é fácil dar certo. Talves isto ajude: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list